# MongoDB: How can I aggregate node values of nested arbitrary k-v objects using the aggregate pipeline?

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I have a structure whereby a user-created object can end up in a specific Document key. I know what the key is, but I have no idea what the structure of the underlying value is. For the purposes of my problem, let's assume it's an array, a single value, or a dictionary.

For extra fun, I am also trying to solve this problem for nested dictionaries.

What I am trying to do is run an aggregation across all objects that have this key, and summarize the values of the terminal nodes of the structure. For example, if I have the following:

```
ObjectA.foo = {"a": 2, "b": 4}
ObjectB.foo = {"a": 8, "b": 16}
ObjectC.bar = {"nested": {"d": 20}}
ObjectD.bar = {"nested": {"d": 30}}
```

I want to end up with an output value of

```
foo.a = 10
foo.b = 20
bar.nested.d = 50
```

My initial thought is to try to figure out how to get Mongo to flatten the keys of the hierarchy. If I could break the source data down from objects to a series of key-values where a key represents the entire path to the value, I could easily do the aggregation on that. However, I am not sure how to do that.

Ideally, I'd have something like $unwindKeys, but alas there is no such operator. There is $objectToArray, which I imagine I could then $unwind, but at that point I already start getting lost in stacking these operators. It also does not answer the problem of arbitrary depth, though I suppose a single-depth solution would be a good start.

Any ideas?

**EDIT**: So I've solved the single-depth problem using [$objectToArray](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/). Behold:

```
db.mytable.aggregate(
  [
    {
      '$project': {
        '_id': false,
        'value': {
          '$objectToArray': '$data.input_field_with_dict'
        } 
      }
    },
    {
      '$unwind': '$value'
    },
    {
      '$group': {
        '_id': '$value.k', 
        'sum': {
          '$sum': '$value.v'
        }
      }
    }
  ]
)
```

This will give you key-value pairs across your chosen docs that you can then iterate on. So in case of my sample above involving ObjectA and ObjectB, the result of the above query would be:

```
{"_id": "a", "sum": 10}
{"_id": "b", "sum": 20}
```

I still don't know how to traverse the structure recursively though. The $objectToArray solution works fine on a single known level with unknown keys, but I don't have a solution if you have both unknown keys and unknown depth.

The search goes on: how do I recursively sum or at least project fields with nested structures and preserve their key sequences? In other words, how do I flatten a structure of unknown depth? If I could flatten, I could easily aggregate on keys at that point.

Comment: Are you saying, you have a collection like this?

`/* 1 */
{
    "a" : 2,
    "b" : 4
}

/* 2 */
{
    "a" : 8,
    "b" : 16
}

/* 3 */
{
    "nested" : {
        "d" : 20
    }
}

/* 4 */
{
    "nested" : {
        "d" : 30
    }
}`

Answer (score 0):

If your collection is like this

```
/* 1 */
{
    "a" : 2,
    "b" : 4
}

/* 2 */
{
    "a" : 8,
    "b" : 16
}

/* 3 */
{
    "nested" : {
        "d" : 20
    }
}

/* 4 */
{
    "nested" : {
        "d" : 30
    }
}
```

the below the query will get you the required result.

```
db.sof.aggregate([
{'$group': {
    '_id': null,
    'a': {$sum: '$a'},
    'b': {$sum: '$b'},
    'd': {$sum: '$nested.d'}
    }}
])
```

Comment: Hey, thank you for the suggestion! Problem is, I don't know what's in the source. I am building an aggregate pipeline to be applied to the entire collection of documents of a given type that have some field that I am putting user-defined arbitrary dictionaries in. So at the time I am building the pipeline I don't actually know what exactly is going to be in the target field "foo," just that it will likely have a dictionary. What I am ultimately aggregating on is then some series of key values, the names of which I do not know. I am not sure if it's possible